Trying to edit an image. Colors look wrong
Here is a 14x14 px Blinky from the Pac-Man game:
https://github.com/jsx97/test/blob/main/blinky.zip

When I try to fill Blinky with the #00ffff color, using Gimp, the color doesn't look correct. Wheres it is expected to be cyan, it is very close to white instead:

Moreover, the eyes are now that same color as well.
I checked the color profile and it seems to be plain good sRGB. So why is that and how to fix it?

Indexed color 8-bit. In your palette are there just 4 colors and perhaps not the cyan...

The PNG image is in Indexed colour mode. The palette contains only four colours: red, dark blue, white, and black.

To edit the colours, first click Image > Mode > RGB. This will convert the image into RGB colour

Select all the red pixels and fill them with the new colour you want

To convert back to Indexed colour mode click Image > Mode > Indexed, and then under Colour Map, select the "Generate optimum palate" option, and set the Maximum number of colours to 4 colours (or however many colours the image actually has)

To save the edited image, click File > Export As, and export as PNG again


Note: This has nothing to do with GIMP. It's because of the way the image was saved when it was created. The same thing happens in other image editors such as Photoshop.

Alternatively (depending on what you're intending to do with the edited graphic, e.g. if you're going to use it as a game asset), consider editing the palette to change the red to cyan.

@Matthew unfortunately there's a bug in GIMP 2.10 which prevents direct editing of the Indexed colour palette. There's a work around which involves duplicating the palette first in the Palette dialog, then editing the colours in the duplicate palette, and then doing Colors > Map > Set Color Map to assign the new palette.  It's a total pain for just changing one colour in an image as simple as the OPs. However, it might be worthwhile for larger more complex images with more colours.

Also worth noting even when editing the duplicate palette there are other issues. You can't see the colour change until you set the colormap - and once you have done it, you can't edit it again without repeating all the tedious steps again. if you want to add more colours there are issues with the tools available in the dialog, and the whole thing is really just too buggy. It was reported some years ago, but still no fix. details of the bug here. Hopefully they'll fix it for GIMP 3.

Wow. Having almost never worked with indexed-color images myself, I was unaware of that. That is surprising that such a basic function would be missing/broken.
